# Using markovify to generate song lyrics that rhyme

Tags: python, python-3.x, markov-chains

I am trying to use the Markovify library to generate song lyrics with a corpus. The problem is that I can't make the lines rhyme.

I have tried:

1) Generate line 1, get the last word of line 1

2) Generate line 2, get the last word of line 2 and check if it rhymes (using the pronouncing library). This is highly inefficient.

I also could have tried this:

1) Generate line 1

2) Generate a word that rhymes with the last word of line 1 and check if the word exists in the corpus. If these conditions are met, generate the rest of the sentence and reverse it. The problem with this is that Markovify doesn't allow for the generation of a sentence when given an input word(in my case the rhyming word).

How can I make the lines rhyme? Thanks.